# How can I debug a docker container initialization?

Tags: docker, debug

I had an issue with a container, even though it builds perfectly it does not properly start. The cause is a workaround I've added to the Dockerfile (for having a self-configured /etc/hosts routing)

```
RUN mkdir -p -- /lib-override /etc-override && cp /lib/libnss_files.so.2 /lib-override
ADD hosts.template /etc-override/hosts
RUN perl -pi -e 's:/etc/hosts:/etc-override/hosts:g' /lib-override/libnss_files.so.2
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /lib-override
```

Obviously there's some error in there, but I wonder how can I get more info on what docker is doing while running. for example, this works:

```
$ docker run image ls
usr bin ...
```

But this doesn't:

```
$ docker run image ls -l
$
```

There is nothing in the logs and I can't call an interactive shell either. I can use strace to see what's happening but I was hoping theres a better way.

Is there any way I can set docker to be more verbose?

**EDIT**: Thanks to Andrew D. I now know what's wrong with the code above (I left it so his answer can be understood). Now the issue is still how might I debug something like this or get some insides at why *ls -l* failed why *ls* did not.

**EDIT**: The -D=true might give more output, though not in my case...

Comment: Please make the effort to mark one of the answers as "accepted", thanks!

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Docker `events` command may help and [Docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command can fetch logs even after the image failed to start.

First start `docker events` in the background to see whats going on.

```
docker events&
```

Then run your failing `docker run ...` command. 
Then you should see something like the following on screen:

```
2015-12-22T15:13:05.503402713+02:00 xxxxxxxacd8ca86df9eac5fd5466884c0b42a06293ccff0b5101b5987f5da07d: (from xxx/xxx:latest) die
```

Then you can get the startup hex id from previous message or the output of the run command. Then you can use it with the logs command:

```
docker logs <copy the instance id from docker events messages on screen>
```

You should now see some output from the failed image startup.

As @alexkb suggested in a comment: `docker events&` can be troublesome if your container is being constantly restarted from something like AWS ECS service. In this scenario it may be easier to get the container hex id out of the logs in `/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.<DATE>`. Then use docker `logs <hex id>`.

Comment: Very helpful! New to docker and was trying to get portainer running. Solved it with these debugging steps. Found someone on Medium.com with the same problem: https://medium.com/@jameson_37151/hey-linda-had-the-same-issue-im-new-to-docker-i-was-running-30776b44d327

Comment: I get "container not found"!?

Comment: Strange. Just to make sure, @dementedhedgehog did you try copy the hex-id from the log message ending in "`(from xxx/xxx:latest) die`"?

Comment: @dementedhedgehog Was the container deleted with the `docker run --rm` option? Can you see the container id using `docker container ls -a`?

Comment: Possibly, though not sure anymore.  If I see it again I'll post with more details.

Comment: Thank you so much this answer, it is a life saver. Only thing to add is that `docker events&` can be troublesome if your container is being constantly restarted from something like AWS ECS service. So in this scenario it may be easier to get the container hex id out of the logs in `/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.<DATE>`. Then use `docker logs <hex id>` as suggested by this answer to see why things aren't booting.

Comment: @alexkb Thanks! I added your suggestion to the end of the answer so others may find it more easily.

Answer (score 26):

Well the best I have found out so far is:

```
#stop the current demon and start it in debug modus
sudo service docker stop
dockerd -D # --debug
```

The just start the client from a new shell. The misconception was to think the client actually does anything at all... well it's just communicating with the daemon, so you don't want to *debug* the client but the daemon itself (normally).

Comment: Dont get it really. But I ran your commands (with `sudo dockerd -D # --debug`) and now all my containers start as expected :)

Answer (score 22):

In my case, the `-a` (attach to STDOUT/STDERR) flag was enough:

```
user@machine:~$ docker start -a server_name
Error: The directory named as part of the path /log/log_path/app.log does not exist.
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

It showed the startup error (in our case, a missing log path used by `supervisord`).  I assume most container startup errors would show up here as well.

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer your question on how to make docker output more complete but I can tell you that in-place regex replacing a string in a .so file is a bit insane: the string only has so much space allocated to it, and if you change the file offsets of other entries, the elf file becomes corrupted. Try running objdump or readelf on your .so file after running the perl command (*before LD_LIBRARY_PATH change*) outside of a container -- dollars to donuts it is now corrupt.

The reason it works [in this sadly necessary hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414543/how-can-i-make-etc-hosts-writable-by-root-in-a-docker-container) is because "tmp" and "etc" are the same string length so no offsets change.  Consider the directory /dkr or similar if you prefer not to use /tmp.

If you MUST take this approach and your desired paths are unchangeable, rebuild the library and change the default path for /etc/hosts in the source. Or better, when building your modified `libnss_files.so` rename it to something like `libnss_altfiles.so` and change `nsswitch.conf` to use `hosts: altfiles` when starting your docker container (unless docker has bind mounted nsswitch.conf as well, then you can't change it). This will let you have the libnss_altfiles.so in parallel with your normal libraries in the base system. If docker does bind-mount nsswitch.conf, leave a copy of your rebuilt libnss_files.so in your /lib-override directory ready to be loaded by LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

As a heads up, suid/sgid binaries ignore LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD, so some stuff is going to break (read: go back to using the default /etc/hosts) if you use those variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great insight... I was too fast and see now what's happening. I still don't know why getting the stat needs to resolve a host (ls -l) while the simple file listing (ls), does not...

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, you can find useful error messages by sshing into the node running the docker daemon and then doing:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/containers/* /var/log/docker.log 2>&1
```

On 'Docker Community edition' on Mac OS, you can connect into the docker vm  by doing:

```
$  screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
```

Comment: `tty` doesn't exist for me (macOS 11.2.3, Docker 20.10.5)

Answer (score 2):

When `docker logs` fail because container is not yet created, it's already possible to "attach" (with the `docker run -a` switch) the error message to `STDERR` (while keeping to `STDOUT`), e.g.:

```
$ docker run -a STDERR -a STDOUT -i --rm --name ml-fs-db mirekphd/ml-fs-db:latest
```

---

*Notice that if you normally run the container in "detached" mode (using the `-d` switch, it will not be compatible with `-a`, hence the use of `-i` as "interactive" here).*